PHP - Multilingual Regex to find and replace strings cleaning all non-letter characters in ALL languages
I was always bad in regex, and now facing a challenge.
TL;DR:
Need a "Catch-all" regex for searched strings with non letters between them for all language sets.
Details:
Need search an array of $strings_to_replace inside any possible $content and replace with a $replacement_string ( single for now )
The challenge is that the regex need to :

Find the $strings_to_replace even if ( actually    especially if  ) they contain any possible NON LETTER character - Call them possible "separators"  that occur in-between the    $strings_to_replace  letters. they can be anything e.g.    ',~,:,&,|,@ even whitespaces or non breaking characters (    tried \w with limited results )

Match all possible "Cases" combinations ( Lower - Upper, CamelCase    and other non-Latin cases )

Work in ALL language sets including all characters ( might it be    Chinese, Japanese, Korean, Cyrillic, Thai or any other LTR or RTL e.g. Hebrew, Arabic etc ..) I guess need the Unicode flag, But I also tried UTF-8 conversion..

Not sure about character chaining limit, there should not be any if possible as long as the chain itself without the separator matches ( see below example EDIT: better see @chrisHass comment below he explains the issue MUCH better than me )


Basically I need all possible matches ( might even have some I did not think of yet, think of it as a sort of "Censor" or certain Type-o corrector )
After so many iterations the code until now is super messy but can illustrate the challenge as well as my desperation :-)-  or maybe I am just over complicating things.
    function o99_chfs_replace_regex_text($content) {

            // Strings to replace -now illustrating with Personal names, and city names, but can actually be any requiered strings

           $strings_to_replace = array(
                
                // Simple Latin 
                'New york', 
                'Paris',    
                'Tokyo',   
                // Some Additional names
                'Fernando',
                'Michael',
                'Francesca',
                
                // Arabic (العربية)
                'نيويورك', // New York
                'باريس',    // Paris
                'طوكيو',    // Tokyo
                'فرناندو',   // Fernando
                'مايكل',     // Michael
                'فرانشيسكا', // Francesca

                // Hebrew (עברית)
                'ניו יורק', // New York
                'פריז',     // Paris
                'טוקיו',    // Tokyo
                
                'פרננדו',   // Fernando
                'מיכאל',    // Michael
                'פרנצ׳סקה', // Francesca

                // Chinese (中文)
                '纽约',    // New York
                '巴黎',    // Paris
                '东京',    // Tokyo
                '费尔南多', // Fernando
                '迈克尔',   // Michael
                '弗兰西斯卡', // Francesca


                // Japanese (日本語)
                'ニューヨーク', // New York
                'パリ',         // Paris
                '東京',         // Tokyo
                'フェルナンド', // Fernando
                'マイケル',      // Michael
                'フランチェスカ', // Francesca

                // Korean (한국어)
                '뉴욕',   // New York
                '파리',   // Paris
                '도쿄',   // Tokyo
                '페르난도', // Fernando
                '마이클',   // Michael
                '프란체스카', // Francesca

                // Russian (Русский)
                'Нью-Йорк', // New York
                'Париж',    // Paris
                'Токио',    // Tokyo
                'Фернандо',  // Fernando
                'Майкл',     // Michael
                'Франческа'  // Francesca

        );




/** Can give other example of special characters 
$special_latin_letters = array(
    'á', 'é', 'í', 'ó', 'ú', // Spanish
    'à', 'è', 'ì', 'ò', 'ù', // Italian
    'ã', 'ẽ', 'ĩ', 'õ', 'ũ', // Portuguese
    'ä', 'ë', 'ï', 'ö', 'ü', // German
    'å', 'ø', 'æ', // Danish
);

.. but a bit pointless, there are so many and I assume everyone understands that
*/
    
            // Replacement string
            $replacement_string = '++Replaced++'; // anyString anyLanguage anyCharacter
    
            // Construct regex pattern, match all variations of strings with possible separators
            $pattern = '/(?<=^|\W|\s|\b)(' . implode('|', array_map(function($string) {
                $length = mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8');
                $regex = '';
                for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                    if ($i > 0) {
                        $regex .= '(?:\W|\s|\b)*'; // Adjusted here
                    }
                    $regex .= preg_quote(mb_substr($string, $i, 1, 'UTF-8'), '/'); // needed ??
                }
                return $regex;
            }, $strings_to_replace)) . ')(?=\W|\s|\b|$)/u'; // add unicode ?
    
            // Perform replacements using regex
            $content = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) use ($replacement_string) {
                // Preserve HTML tags
                return preg_replace('/' . preg_quote($matches[1], '/') . '/', $replacement_string, $matches[0]);
            }, $content);
        
    
        return $content;
    } 

so given the example $content :
        // much easier generating these random "disturbances" 
        // in php  than catching them with regex

        fRanCE-sca OtherPartsOfContent NoNeedToReplaceTHIS
        fRanc+esc0a OtherPartsOfContent NoNeedToReplaceTHIS
        Fr--ance. sca // spaces and multiple "separators"
        NoNeedToReplaceTHIS
        Pa @ris // white spaces
        pa..RIS //
        P.a.r.i.s // even single character as long as the chain without separator match
        miCh.ael // randomly changed cases
        Mich~ ael
        Mic-ha.el
        NoNeedToReplaceTHIS
        To_-_ky9o // multiple separators occurrences
        To{ky}o // multiple separators occurrences
       OtherPartsOfContent NoNeedToReplaceTHIS to[K]Y.o OtherPartsOfContent NoNeedToReplaceTHIS
        T- ok .yo
       /// etc...

Expected Output would be :
       ++Replaced++ OtherPartsOfContent NoNeedToReplaceTHIS
        ++Replaced++
       NoNeedToReplaceTHIS
        ++Replaced++
        ++Replaced++
        ++Replaced++
        ++Replaced++
        ++Replaced++
        ++Replaced++
       NoNeedToReplaceTHIS
        ++Replaced++
        ++Replaced++
      OtherPartsOfContent NoNeedToReplaceTHIS  ++Replaced++ OtherPartsOfContent NoNeedToReplaceTHIS
        ++Replaced++

Honestly, at this point of my trials and errors I am not even sure if it is possible in a single iteration or single expression, but like above said, I am very far from being a regex wizard.
This question and This might come close, but (A) I could not make those patters work as polyglottal for the languages tries and (B) requirements are not exactly the same as "filtering".
Hope the requirements are clear.
Anyone up to the challenge ?

Maybe it would help if you described, in simple terms, what you're trying to accomplish? Why do this in the first place? It sounds quite complex and messy, something you would try to avoid if at all possible.

@KIKOSoftware - I said in the question - it's a sort of "Censor" for some system where people might try to write BaD Wo.rd-s or the likes. And yes, it is VERY messy hence my problem / issue / challenge.

OK, I must have missed that when reading your question. A "bad word" filter is a clear goal. I guess that something like Profanity doesn't do what you want? I my experience people always find ways around word filters.

A non-letter char and - here, I presume you want to exclude whitespace, too - can be matched with [^\p{L}\s]. So, just put [^\p{L}\s]* between each letter of the words you are trying to match.

@KIKOSoftware 1 -you did not missed that, it was me who forgot to write it ( was sure I did must have been dropped somehow in initial editing ) sorry for that.  2 -  no, libraries like profanity would not work ( also because it is not only for profanity - it's just the easiest case to explain )  - but thanks for the tip I was not familiar with that.

Just for reference, using the rules as I understand them, although non-sensical, The boy said "I saw a cat!" Ok. You know I don't care. contains tokyo, and Fern and Ophelia went to the store. contains Fernando.

Yeah, because you include spaces. I do not think you should.

@ChrisHaas Yes you are right I referred to this issue in point #4  ( maybe wrongly addressed as "character chaining" limit ) but actually the list of $strings_to_replace for me is not that long, and thus the probability of such a coincidence scenario is VERY low IMHO to be worth the risk of destructing some "good words" phrase every once in a trillion or so trials.

Also, are you considering things such as , `ℯ`, `Fʀᴀɴᴄᴇ` and ?

@ChrisHaas Nope, at least not until I saw your message. But for my use case I would be satisficed with sticking to "Normal" keyboard letters of different languages.

The task seems to be too complicated for a simple regex replace. I would

Map the source text to a skeleton by removing non-letters and turning letters to lowercase without accents. For this I would use PHP's built-in Transliterator. One might also consider using Symfony's ASCII slugger. Alternatively, the uspoof_getSkeleton() function from ICU could have been used to map optically similar characters (e.g. Greek capital Eta H or Cyrillic capital En Н into Latin capital Aitch H), but it is not ported to PHP (although  the ICU library is used by PHP's Spoofchecker under the hood).

Search for "badwords" in the skeleton and replace them. The trick in replacement is to keep track of character positions during transliteration. For that I split the input string into graphemes, and transliterate each grapheme individually as given in step 1. Then I create a table that maps character positions of the folded string back to the original. For splitting, I used grapheme_extract() with GRAPHEME_EXTR_COUNT to keep together combined emojis like , but I could have equivalently used preg_match_all('/\X/u', $str, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) as well. Alternatively, grapheme_extract() with GRAPHEME_EXTR_MAXCHARS, or preg_match_all('/./u', ...), or IntlCodePointBreakIterator would split emojis into unicode code points. For most scripts, the two approaches are the same, and emojis, we ignore them anyway.


And here comes the working example:
<?php

/** Transliterator folding to lowercase and removing accents, punctuations, etc. */
$folder = \Transliterator::create('NFD; [:^Letter:] Remove; Lower(); NFC;');
// Alternatively, this would transliterate every script to Latin,
// and also map `Париж` to `pariz` and `` to `france`:
// $folder = \Transliterator::create('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; NFKD; [:^Letter:] Remove; Lower(); NFC;');

/** Folds a string lowering case and removing accents, punctuations, etc. */
function fold(string $str): string
{
    global $folder;
    return $folder->transliterate($str);
}

// One might also consider Symfony's `ASCII slugger`, which can be installed with the
// bash command `composer require symfony/translation-contracts symfony/string`.
/*
spl_autoload_register();
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Symfony\Component\String\Slugger\AsciiSlugger;
$slugger = new AsciiSlugger();
function fold(string $str): string
{
    global $slugger;
    return (string) $slugger->slug($str, '')->lower();
}
*/

/** 
 * Folds a string and creates grapheme position table.
 * 
 * The table maps graphemes of the folded string back to the original string. The
 * returned array stores byte positions of the folded graphemes as keys, and a pair
 * of `[start, prev_end]` as values, where `start` is the byte position of the
 * corresponding unfolded grapheme in the original string, while `prev_end` is the
 * byte position in the original string where the previous folded grapheme ended +1.
 * The last array element is `folded_length => [unfolded_length, last_end]`. The keys
 * `-1` and `-2` hold the folded and the normalized original strings, resp.
 * 
 * E.g., if `_à..B_` is folded into `aB`, then the returned array is `[-1 => "aB", -2
 * => "_à..B_", 0 => [1,0], 1 => [5,3], 2 => [7,6]]`. (Note that the grapheme `à` is
 * 2-byte long.)
 */function foldMap(string $str): array
{
    static $cache = [];
    global $folder;
    if (!\normalizer_is_normalized($str))
        $str = \normalizer_normalize($str);
    $ret = [-1 => &$folded, -2 => $str];
    $folded = '';
    $folded_pos = 0;
    $start = $prev_end = 0;
    while (false !== ($grapheme = \grapheme_extract($str, 1, \GRAPHEME_EXTR_COUNT, $start, $next))) {
        if ('' !== ($cache[$grapheme] ??= fold($grapheme))) {
            $ret[$folded_pos] = [$start, $prev_end];
            $folded .= $cache[$grapheme];
            $folded_pos += \strlen($cache[$grapheme]);
            $prev_end = $next;
        }
        $start = $next;
    }
    $ret[\strlen($folded)] = [$start, $prev_end];
    return $ret;
}

/**
 * Folds the subject string and searches for the pattern. If a match is found in the
 * folded subject, it is replaced with the replacement text in the original unfolded
 * subject.
 */
function myReplace(string $pattern, string $replace, string $subject)
{
    $map = foldMap($subject);
    $subject = $map[-2]; // Normalizer_normalized original.
    if (\preg_match_all($pattern, $map[-1], $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)) {
        // Start replacing matches from the end of string!
        foreach (\array_reverse($m[0]) as [$match_folded, $start_folded]) {
            $start_orig = $map[$start_folded][0];
            $end_folded = $start_folded + \strlen($match_folded);
            $end_orig = $map[$end_folded][1];
            $len_orig = $end_orig - $start_orig;
            $subject = \substr_replace($subject, $replace, $start_orig, $len_orig);
        }
    }
    return $subject;
}

$strings_to_replace = array(
    // Simple Latin 
    'New york',
    'Paris',
    'Tokyo',
    // Some Additional names
    'Fernando',
    'Michael',
    'Francesca',

    // Arabic (العربية)
    'نيويورك', // New York
    'باريس',    // Paris
    'طوكيو',    // Tokyo
    'فرناندو',   // Fernando
    'مايكل',     // Michael
    'فرانشيسكا', // Francesca

    // Hebrew (עברית)
    'ניו יורק', // New York
    'פריז',     // Paris
    'טוקיו',    // Tokyo

    'פרננדו',   // Fernando
    'מיכאל',    // Michael
    'פרנצ׳סקה', // Francesca

    // Chinese (中文)
    '纽约',    // New York
    '巴黎',    // Paris
    '东京',    // Tokyo
    '费尔南多', // Fernando
    '迈克尔',   // Michael
    '弗兰西斯卡', // Francesca


    // Japanese (日本語)
    'ニューヨーク', // New York
    'パリ',         // Paris
    '東京',         // Tokyo
    'フェルナンド', // Fernando
    'マイケル',      // Michael
    'フランチェスカ', // Francesca

    // Korean (한국어)
    '뉴욕',   // New York
    '파리',   // Paris
    '도쿄',   // Tokyo
    '페르난도', // Fernando
    '마이클',   // Michael
    '프란체스카', // Francesca

    // Russian (Русский)
    'Нью-Йорк', // New York
    'Париж',    // Paris
    'Токио',    // Tokyo
    'Фернандо',  // Fernando
    'Майкл',     // Michael
    'Франческа'  // Francesca

);

/** Creates folded pattern of bad words. */
$badwords_pattern = \implode('|', \array_map('fold', $strings_to_replace));

$test_text = 'fRanCE-sca OtherPartsOfContent NoNeedToReplaceTHIS
fRanc+esc0a OtherPartsOfContent NoNeedToReplaceTHIS
Fr--ance. sca // spaces and multiple "separators"
NoNeedToReplaceTHIS
Pa @ris // white spaces
pa..RIS //
P.a.r.i.s // even single character as long as the chain without separator match
miCh.ael // randomly changed cases
Mich~ ael
Mic-ha.el
NoNeedToReplaceTHIS
To_-_ky9o // multiple separators occurrences
To{ky}o // multiple separators occurrences
OtherPartsOfContent NoNeedToReplaceTHIS to[K]Y.o OtherPartsOfContent NoNeedToReplaceTHIS
T- ok .yo
';/**/

echo myReplace("/$badwords_pattern/", '++Replaced++', $test_text) . PHP_EOL;

